# Stroke width tool equivalent in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, stroke

Is there a tool in Inkscape similar to the stroke **Width Tool** in Illustrator? In other words, is there a way to manipulate the width of a stroke by setting the weight at a given position or anchor point along the path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is the PowerStroke. In version 1.0, it will be possible to draw it with pressure sensitivity with the Pencil tool. Currently, the effect can be added via the 'Shape' option of the Pen/Pencil tool, or via the Path Effects dialog.

[image]

From [wiki page on PowerStroke](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/PowerStroke):

- When added, the Path Effect PowerStroke produces 3 additional pink handles that can be dragged around intuitively:

  - A pink handle can be moved along the length of the path to define where it should have its effect.
  - A pink handle can be dragged away from or closer to the center of the path to make the stroke at this position thicker or thinner.
- To add another pink handle, you can duplicate one of the existing ones with CTRL-Click, and then drag it away along the path.
- To remove a pink handle, CTRL-ALT-Click on it.
- To position a pink handle at exact coordinates, Shift+Click or ALT-Click on it, an entry box opens.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I can't wait for version 1.0 to come out. I'm currently using the `0.92+devel` version from snapcraft and it's missing some functionality, like printing for example.

Comment: I have only recently added instructions for printing when using the snap (need to copy over to the master branch snap...): 
https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-0.92.3/gnulinux/snap/dl/ 

However, if you're on Ubuntu, you will have an easier time using the ppa. 
https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-master/gnulinux/ubuntu/ppa/dl/

Comment: Oh, and the 0.92+devel version has the pencil pressure sensitivity with PowerStroke.

Comment: Is there a ppa for the 0.92+devel version?

Comment: Yes, see link in my previous comment.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did: add ppa, update, install. The usual. But I get the following one: `Inkscape 0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11)`. It seems like the `inkscape.dev/trunk` ppa is ignored, or the main repo source is preferred (`Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 inkscape amd64 0.92.3-4`). I'm on Pop!_OS 18.10.

Comment: What does 'apt-cache policy inkscape' say?

Comment: ```inkscape:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.92.3-4
  Version table:
     0.92.3-4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Then neither the ppa has been added, nor is Inkscape installed. Try to add the ppa again (if pop os supports those? Never heard of that distro before...)

Comment: Well, pop definitely supports them. I use them for other packages as well. Pop!_OS is the distro of [system76](https://system76.com/) and it is very close to Ubuntu. Adding the Inkscape.dev ppa does not yield any errors, nor is it added. I did remove Inkscape (`0.92.3-4`) before posting the ouput of `apt-cache policy inkscape`. Here it is with Inkscape installed. ```inkscape:
  Installed: 0.92.3-4
  Candidate: 0.92.3-4
  Version table:
 *** 0.92.3-4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the ppa either via all possible ways: the update manager, the command line, by editing the files?

Comment: Ok, just checked the "Extra sources" tab in Repoman and the PPA is added (http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/trunk/ubuntu). Also, `sudo apt update` shows the inkscape PPA. But apt-cache is still showing the Ubuntu repo. Also tried installing a specific version (e.g. `sudo apt install inkscape=0.92+devel`) but that doesn't do it, either.

Comment: apt-cache policy should include all available Inkscape versions. Can you check if there is maybe no compiled version of master for cosmic in the ppa? Edit: checked myself. It's there: https://launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/trunk?field.series_filter=cosmic

Comment: Direct link to deb package: https://launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/trunk/+files/inkscape-trunk_0.92.0+devel+201812120336~ubuntu18.10.1_amd64.deb

Comment: After trying to remove and add the ppa multiple times, still no luck. The apt-cache policy still only shows the current stable. From the main repo. ```inkscape:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.92.3-4
  Version table:
     0.92.3-4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: I downloaded the deb package directly and installed that one. After installing, Pop!_OS instantly notified me of an update (as it should). So now I am on tonight's build (Version: `1:0.92.0+devel+201812130338~ubuntu18.10.1`). Although, the PPA doesn't work in my case, I am happy to be in the loop with the deb package now. So I can finally print, which was the main reason to ditch the snap build. :) Thanks so much for your time and help!